# camera preview can not be save to png

Tags: android, bitmap, png, surfaceview

I have drawn a transparent png on the camera in the surface view. When I save the cached bitmap to a PNG file, only the thing I've drawn is saved, the camera preview image is black.

```
cv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
//  Bitmap
bb=Bitmap.createBitmap(cv.getWidth(),cv.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Bitmap bb=  cv.getDrawingCache();
//  cv.draw(new Canvas(bb));
String fn=System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
OutputStream o=new FileOutputStream(new File(sd,fn));
bb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, o);
```